# WINE Steam freezes at "Connecting Steam account"

Tags: wine, steam, playonlinux

As of yesterday, trying to start Steam through WINE only brings up the `Connecting Steam Account: <username>` dialog, and then freezes entirely, requiring the process to be forcibly killed.

I have already tried restarting my PC, reinstalling Steam in a new wineprefix, and adding a `-tcp` command line flag, all to no avail.

I have also determined that it is likely not a connection issue, as starting Steam for Linux works and connects fine, and I am logged out of Linux Steam whenever I start WINE Steam (indicating a connection was successfully established)

I am using PlayOnLinux to manage WINE.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it appears restarting my computer fixed the issue. Maybe I got something wrong here.